# Orchard 1.8 'shapeTracingMetadataHost is not defined'

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I am trying to play with some of the designer tools for Orchard 1.8 to understand how some of the overall architecture works, but when I enable the Shape Tracing module I get a ton of these: `Uncaught ReferenceError: shapeTracingMetadataHost is not defined.`

The HTML seems to be generated for some of it so I can poke through there in trying to figure out layout processes, but any suggestions on what might cause this? It does seem to work with The Theme Machine which uses jQuery 1.9.1, however we're using the latest jQuery (via `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>` so is that potentially the source of this?

Comment: Did you by any chance install a version of Designer Tools that is different from the Orchard version that you're using? Also verify that your theme's document.cshtml has a Tail zone defined.

Comment: I had installed a version of Designer Tools, but that broke the whole site so (thankfully!) I restored from the automatic backup that had been created. I deleted the one out of Orchard.Modules that I had installed and copied the one in from _Backup and everything came back. My document.cshtml file has `@Display(Model.Tail)` in it as well. The HTML generates for all the shape stuff, but with the JS errors it just can't render.

Comment: Any guesses on this? Is it an incompatibility with jQuery 2.0+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not bring the latest jQuery. Always use `Script.Require("jQuery")`. jQuery is a shared resource. Let the platform decide which version to use. Not doing so means that you'll get multiple versions of the same script included, and any breaking change in jQuery (and those are common) will break random things.

Comment: That worked. I dropped back to jQuery from Orchard (using `Script.Require` and tracing works great. Are there plans to update to 2.x in the mix?